# Need open-source GUI for form-data

Tags: open-source, python, database

Disclaimer: I'm not a programmer, just a SQL guy. Forgive me if my question(s) and/or responses frustrate.

I'm hoping there is a currently existing solution out there someone could point me to. I am looking for an open-source solution for form-data that uses a SQL backend. This is a potential project I think could work for my employer. Basically, all I need is a GUI interface that communicates with a SQL DB (we currently use MSSQL, but can use MySQL if need be) for basic form data. The GUI would need to have read/write ability to DB, and by the same token, edits made to DB directly (via TSQL statements) would need to reflect in GUI. GUI would ideally contain functionality for uploading/retrieving files (text/image/pdf), also from SQL. I would love a Python-based solution (as that is the language I have interest in learning), but whatever open-source solution there is will work. Obviously, open-source is needed as I will need to tailor the program to my needs. Also, I am not looking for a web-based solution. I want a local application that is fed by the DB, which would provide the inter-connectivity. I hope I'm using the right terminology to convey what I'm seeking.

Big thanks in advance!

*requirements: basically, all I'm looking to do is have a window that has editable fields, and other windows that hold relationships based on a unique identifier. For example, this is all based on a person's name. when searched/selected, the initial window will hold vital info (name, address, dob, etc.) but there will be buttons/links to other windows that hold other data such as organizations they belong to, or another button to show a window that contains what products they have purchased. All this data is stored in SQL. This is only to be a desktop application that interfaces with SQL. I hope this clarifies what I'm after.

Comment: If you could switch from Python to PHP ( a few lines of code only) and use MySql, then look at https://www.grocerycrud.com/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for pointing this out, I'm looking into it!

Answer (score 1):

There's not much detail in your specification ("a GUI interface that communicates with a SQL DB"), but regardless of what your detailed specifications are, you're not likely to find an existing application that exactly meets them.  So you're going to have to build your own.  If you want to do this in Python, you can use the Tkinter GUI library that is part of the Python distribution, and the Python database API is easy to use and there are connector libraries for most or all common RDBMS'.  You can find supplementary libraries for database access and for GUI applications (both Tkinter and others) on PyPI (https://pypi.org).

Comment: That is slowly becoming the answer I'm getting to, that I'll have to build it lol As opposed to Tkinter, what can you tell me about using visual studio to flesh out a GUI?

Comment: Nothing; sorry.  I haven't used VS in many years.